# compare ntext by string in sql server 2005 by linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2005

How can I compare ntext type in sql server 2005 to string with linq?

in sql server 2005;

```
@a as ntext
```

linq in c#;

```
string b;

var k=from p in DataContext.TableName 

where p.a.toString()==b)

select p;

//return k=null
```

Comment: `NTEXT` is deprecated and should no longer be used - use NVARCHAR(MAX) instead. That type would be much easier to deal with, too!

Comment: i do not define max for this variable

Comment: aren't you forgetting the table/entity name after the DataContext word?

Answer (score 1):

NTEXT columns cannot be compared. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175795%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ea7052c6-9aa2-44f7-96ca-ee68ef179cfd/)

If you work on 2005 or higher, convert NTEXT to NVARCHAR(MAX), as others have already suggested.

Comment: This is not entirely true. As it even mentions (at least in the link to the MSDN Forum) they ARE comparable using the LIKE clause. This is also being discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002514/sql-server-in-asd-not-working-when-column-is-ntext  However, I am not sure if this helps at all with a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in linq2sql using the static "Like" method of the System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods class.

```
string b;

var k=from p in DataContext.TableName 

where System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like(p.a, b)

select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

If using linq2sql then your pseudocode is correct - although you won't need to use .ToString() and obviously you'd need to match the brackets.

Also, as already noted in the comments, NVARCHAR(MAX) is now the preferred data type instead of NTEXT