# SQL Server: IN ('asd') not working when column is NTEXT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sqldatatypes, in-operator

How can I fix this problem?

```
where someNtext IN ('asd',asd1')
```

gives an error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line XXXXX
>   The data types ntext and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: Is the missing leading `'` for the `'asd1'` parameter just a typo??

Comment: `NTEXT` is known to be a really hard to deal with data type - I would recommend switching to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which is much easier to use and work with!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `IN` list is just short-hand for OR conditions. The `LIKE` clause works with `NTEXT` and `TEXT` fields. So, you can combine those two ideas to do this:

```
WHERE (
       someNtext LIKE N'asd'
OR     someNtext LIKE N'asd1'
      )
```

However, as @marc_s suggested in a comment on the Question, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is preferred as all string functions work with it (and the `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, and `IMAGE` datatypes have been deprecated as of SQL Server 2005).  You *could* do an inline convert such as:

```
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), someNtext) IN (N'asd', N'asd1')
```

but likely that would not perform as well as using the `LIKE` clause with `OR` conditions.

**Please note:** When working with `NTEXT` / `NVARCHAR` / `NCHAR` / `XML` data, it is best to *always* prefix string literals with an uppercase "N". Not doing so can result in data loss for any characters not supported by the code page associated with the default collation of the database.

For more information on working with collations / encodings / Unicode / strings in general in SQL Server, please visit: https://Collations.Info/

Comment: I think it's better to avoid the use of this type, don't you think?

Comment: If you have a choice when creating the columns then yes, by all means avoid TEXT, NTEXT, and IMAGE as they are deprecated and will likely be removed from a future version of SQL Server. However, if working on a system that was done in SQL Server 2000 and then upgraded to a newer version and you don't have the ability to change the column datatype, then it works just fine to use the LIKE clause. Ideally you would have the opportunity to rebuild the table with the NVARCHAR(MAX) datatype,  but sometimes people work on packages from a 3rd party developer and cannot make the change.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx:

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Answer (score -2):

NText is not comparable, don't use it if you need compare use nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: Please remove this answer as it is specifically false.  An NTEXT field IS comparable using the LIKE clause.